# Скачивание файла через скрипт

Tags: php

Нужно отдать юзеру .rar-архив на скачивание.

```
<?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
 header("Connection: close");                   
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
 header("Content-Type: application/rar"); 
 header("Content-Length: ".filesize('1.rar'));       
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1.rar"); 
 readfile('1.rar'); 
 ?>
```

Проблема в том, что архивы в пару килобайт скачивает нормально, а вот если скачать архив в 10 мб, то пишет, что повреждён. В чём проблема?

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что php умирает после 30 секунд работы.

Comment: 10 минут стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдавать файлы средствами PHP - очень сомнительная идея.

Предлагаю Вам такой вариант с использованием nginx (так как он, говорят, работает со статикой лучше, чем Apache).

Чтобы скачать файл, пользователь должен перейти на некоторую страницу, к примеру:

```
/getFile.php?fileId=$fileID
```

После чего Вы по fileId определяете, что это за файл, и узнаете его путь, после того, как Вы узнали пусть, Вы создаете симлинк (symlink) на этот файл, например, в директории:

```
 /usersFiles/
```

(там хранить только симлинки), при этом, имя симлинка - это, к примеру, `md5()` от оригинального пути к файлу + его расширение.
После того как Вы сгенерировали симлинк, Вы перенаправляете пользователя на него:

```
Header('location: http://site.site/usersFiles/'.$symLink);
```

Пользователь переходит на этот симлинк и счастливый качает файл.

Для удаления симлинков Вы можете раз в несколько минут запускать сприпт по крону, который будет удалять все симлинки, созданные больше минуты назад, или же делать `sleep(5)` в скрипте, который генерирует симлинк и удалять его.

Тест под виндой показал, что после удаления симлинка nginx не прерывает отдачу файла по адресу симлинка. Думаю, под linux ситуация такая же, но для начала все же проверьте.

**UPD**

Кстати, PHP из коробки умеет делать 
[симлинки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.symlink.php).

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй просто `<a href="file.rar">Скачать архив</a>`.

Обычно архивы скачиваются по прямой ссылке на файл.
Проще даже так сделать, потому что на php больше и разницы никакой нету.

Comment: Нужно скрыть истинный путь к файлу, поэтому и пхп...

Comment: @Rammsteinik поздравляю! Вот только сейчас мы об этом и узнали.

Comment: Не стал бы трогать пхп, написал бы просто хреф.